# Why a new sequence is generated in PostgreSQL Database when the table is altered?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, sails.js, sequence

I have a project deployed in google cloud and using a Postgres database. The backend was written in Sails js. My question is when I altered a table (added a new column to the video table), USER table and VIDEO table sequences have created again with start value 1.

[image]

Then the newly created sequence (say `USER_id_seq1` and `VIDEO_id_seq1`) have been selected as the default sequence in respective tables.

[image]

Earlier I was altering tables with sails js

```
migrate: 'alter'
```

And I also tried SQL `ALTER TABLE` query to alter these tables. Still, I couldn't find why these sequences are auto-generated. I am new to PostgreSQL. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You...

Comment: Which product in Google Cloud Platform have you used to deploy the application? Also, are you using PostgreSQL for Cloud SQL?

Comment: @Prabir I'm using cloud run and cloud SQL.

Comment: Your question seems to be not very clear. Can you explain in more detail what you wanted to happen and what is happening instead by editing the question?